# Functions with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question about a convergence of functions with compact support.

SETTING

Let $d\geq 3$ and  $U \subset \mathbb{R^{d}}$ be open and $dx$= Lebesgue measure on $U$.

Let $b_{i},c,d_{i} \in L^{1}_{loc}(U;dx) ,\,1 \leq i \leq d$, such that
$cdx-\sum_{i=1}^{d} \frac{\partial b_{i}}{\partial x_{i}} \geq 0$ and $cdx-\sum_{i=1}^{d} \frac{\partial d_{i}}{\partial x_{i}} \geq0$

in the sense of Schwartz distributions.

Suppose $b_{i}+d_{i} \in L^{d}_{loc}(U;dx)$, $1\leq i \leq d$, and $c \in L^{d/2}_{loc}(U;dx)$ then I want to show the following assertion:

For any $u_{n} \in C_{0}^{\infty}(U)$, $n=1,2,\cdots$, with $u_{n}\to0$ and $\frac{\partial u_{n}}{\partial x_{i}}\to 0 $, $1\leq i \leq d$, in $L^{2}(U;dx)$ there exists a subsequence $(u_{n_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ with $u_{n_{k}} \to 0$ $\mu$-a.e.

Here $\mu=2cdx-\sum_{i=1}^{d} \frac{\partial(b_{i}+d_{i})}{\partial x_{i}}$ (positive radon measure)

Solution(unfinished)

For any $v \in C_{0}^{\infty}(U)$, $v \geq0 $ on $U$, put $h_{n}=u_{n}v\quad(n=1,2,...)$ . Then ${\rm supp}\,h_{n} \subset K$ for some compact set $K \subset U$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{2} \int h_{n}^{2} d \mu&=& \int _{K} h_{n}^{2} d\mu\\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^{d} \int_{K} h_{n} \frac{\partial h_{n}}{ \partial x_{i}} (b_{i}+d_{i})dx+\int_{K} h_{n}^{2}c dx\\
&\leq& \left( \sum_{i=1}^{d} \|h_{n}1_{K}(b_{i}+d_{i})\|_{L^{2}(dx)}^{2}  \right)^{1/2} 
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\left\|1_{K}\frac{\partial h_{n}}{ \partial x_{i}}\right\|^{2}_{L^{2}(dx)} \right)^{1/2} +\|h_{n}^{2}1_{K}c \|_{L^{1}(dx)}\\
&\leq&\left( \sum_{i=1}^{d} \|h_{n}1_{K}(b_{i}+d_{i})\|_{L^{2}(dx)}^{2}  \right)^{1/2} 
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{d}\left\|\frac{\partial h_{n}}{ \partial x_{i}}\right\|^{2}_{L^{2}(dx)} \right)^{1/2} +\|h_{n}^{2}1_{K}c \|_{L^{1}(dx)}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

By the following inequality (It is called Sobolev Lemma): $\exists C>0$ s.t. $\forall u \in C_{0}^{\infty}(U)$,
$
\|u\|_{L^{q}(dx)} \leq C  \left(\sum_{i=1}^{d} \int \left|\frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_{i}} \right|^{2}dx \right)^{1/2}$ where $1/q+1/d=1/2$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\|h_{n}1_{K}(b_{i}+d_{i})\|_{L^{2}(dx)} \leq C_{1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{d}  \left\| \frac{\partial h_{n}}{\partial x_{i}} \right\|^{2}_{L^{2}(dx)} \right)^{1/2} \|1_{K}(b_{i}+d_{i})\|_{L^d(dx)}
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\|u_{n}^{2}1_{K}c\|_{L^{1}(dx)} \leq C_{2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{d}  \left\| \frac{\partial h_{n}}{\partial x_{i}} \right\|^{2}_{L^{2}(dx)} \right)^{1/2} \|1_{K}c\|_{L^{d/2}(dx)}
\end{eqnarray*}

Since $u_{n}\to0$ and $\frac{\partial u_{n}}{\partial x_{i}}\to 0 $, $1\leq i \leq d$, in $L^{2}(U;dx)$, $\sum_{i=1}^{d}  \left\| \frac{\partial h_{n}}{\partial x_{i}} \right\|^{2}_{L^{2}(dx)}\to 0$

Hence $\int h_{n}^{2} d\mu \to 0$ and there exists $(h_{n_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ with $h_{n_{k}} \to 0$ $\mu$-a.e. . Because $h_{n_{k}}=u_{n_{k}}v$ $k=1,2,...$ and ${\rm supp}\,v \subset K$, I can get $u_{n_{k}}\to 0$ $\mu$-a.e. on ${\rm supp}\,v $. Can I get $u_{n_{k}}\to 0 $ $\mu$-a.e.? Thanks.